# Excel Summarise Data by Month and Category

Tags: excel

I have a data set similar to the following:

```
Type    Date        Cat     SubCat    Amount
Income  2017-01-25  Income  Salary    1000
Expense 2017-01-02  Bills   Rent       520
Expense 2017-01-03  Food    Groceries   30
Expense 2017-01-04  Food    Groceries   50
Income  2017-02-25  Income  Salary    1000
Expense 2017-02-05  Bills   Rent       520
Expense 2017-02-06  Bills   Phone       35
Expense 2017-02-07  Food    Bar         20
Expense 2017-02-08  Food    Groceries   20
```

What I would like to do is summarise the amount by the month and the subcategory and put the new data in a table that looks something like this:

[image: New Table]

Is there a way to do this? To get a similar table I guess I could use pivot tables, but I would like the categories to be present even though it doesn't contain any data, which a pivot doesn't.

Will this be possible using an IF formula for every cell or does someone know any other possible tool? Entering a formula for every cell seems a bit messy. Is it easier if they are converted to tables using the format table function?

Thanks!

Comment: Try a pivot table.

Comment: I just added a Type/category/subcategory to your data; left the amount cell blank, and the Pivot table updated to show the category, with nothing in the amount cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a pivot table would probably get you what you need. If you aren't familiar with pivot tables I've put some hints below.

Put Type, cat and subcat in the row labels box. Put date in the column labels box. Drop amount in the values box.

Right click on the date field (along the top)and choose Group. Group by Month.

Good luck.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering, and sorry for my delayed response. One of the reasons that I didn't want to use pivot tables is that I don't like the way the design looks. It doesn't give a very clean look and seems pretty rigid, but maybe that's just because I haven't used the tool that much. Thanks again!